# No write access to my macintosh HD

Tags: mac

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on my macbook pro in conjunction with OSX( that I hadly ever use ).

Of late I'm being refused write access to my Macintosh HD partition that used to work well before. In order to get it to write, I now have to log into OSX, enable journaling, disable journaling and then log into Ubuntu!

Does anyone have a solution to permanently give my my write access again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I have searched the internet for answers but all answers are pretty much the same and not solving my issue. I can read from HFS drives and have disabled the Journaling via Mac OS, but still can't write.
Forcing the rw on mount command does nothing.